# Postgres AT TIME ZONE function shows wrong time?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, jodatime

I am using transformation to new timezone UTC+3 which is equal to EAT timezone, but Postgres (9.1) shows the wrong time

```
select '2015-01-13 08:40:00.0'::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+03', 
       '2015-01-13 08:40:00.0'::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'EAT';
```

(default timezone is Stockholm here)

The result is

```
"2015-01-13 04:40:00",
"2015-01-13 10:40:00"
```

Why?

it should be 2015-01-13 10:40:00

if using JodaTime with both timezones then it shows the same correct result '2015-01-13 10:40:00'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A time zone name spelled like 'UTC+3:00' is a POSIX time zone specification.
In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

Answer (score 8):

From the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) there is the option to use `::timestamptz` instead of `::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE` and I found preferred results when making the conversion; as it is the most concise of the available options while still being readable.

```
SELECT created_at
      ,created_at::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EDT' -- yields bad result
      ,created_at::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'EDT'
      ,created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'EDT'
      ,created_at::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'EDT'
```

---

```
2019-03-29 18:49:25.250431 -- raw UTC data
2019-03-29 22:49:25.250431 -- erroneous result  
2019-03-29 14:49:25.250431 -- accurate result    
2019-03-29 14:49:25.250431 -- accurate result   
2019-03-29 14:49:25.250431 -- accurate result
```

Comment: SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Mexico_City', this gave me the correct result. Thanks brother!

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, it gave me the wrong date and time but this answer here gave me a clear understanding and fixed my problem. [PostgreSQL wrong converting from timestamp without time zone to timestamp with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277170/postgresql-wrong-converting-from-timestamp-without-time-zone-to-timestamp-with-t)

So what I did was changing from

```
SELECT timestamp AT TIME ZONE '+08' FROM orders;
```

to

```
SELECT timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE '+08' FROM orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

EAT(East Africa Time) is three hours ahead of UTC (UTC+03:00).

It's represented as `UTC+03:00` in ISO-8601 format.

But `AT TIME ZONE` only supports timezones represented in **POSIX-style**.

In POSIX-style, the positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.)

| Format | PST | ART | W←UTC→E | EAT | HKT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISO-8601 | UTC-08 | UTC-03 | UTC+00 | UTC+03 | UTC+08 |
| POSIX-style | UTC+08 | UTC+03 | UTC+00 | UTC-03 | UTC-08 |

In POSIX-style, the correct representation of EAT can be:

- 'UTC-03'
- 'UTC-3'
- '-3'
- -3

The result of the following SQL statement must be `TRUE`.

```
select now() at time zone -3 = now() at time zone 'EAT';
```

---

Confusingly, `set time zone` statement supports ISO-8601, not POSIX-style.

Execute the following SQL statements in sequence to find the difference.

| # | SQL | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ① | set time zone -3; | SET |
| ② | select now(); | 2022-02-24 04:53:41.921391-03 |
| ③ | select timestamp '2022-02-24 12:00' at time zone -3; | 2022-02-24 06:00:00-03 |
| ④ | select timestamp '2022-02-24 12:00' at time zone +3; | 2022-02-24 12:00:00-03 |
| ⑤ | set time zone 3; | SET |
| ⑥ | select now(); | 2022-02-24 10:54:10.283953+03 |
| ⑦ | select timestamp '2022-02-24 12:00' at time zone -3; | 2022-02-24 12:00:00+03 |
| ⑧ | select timestamp '2022-02-24 12:00' at time zone +3; | 2022-02-24 18:00:00+03 |
| ⑨ | set time zone local; | SET |
| ⑩ | select now(); | 2022-02-24 15:54:51.79643+08 |
| ⑪ | select now() at time zone -3; | 2022-02-24 10:55:02.209886 |
| ⑫ | select now() at time zone 3; | 2022-02-24 04:55:09.498461 |

**⚠️Please be careful about this.**

---

References:

- [AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)
- [Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)
- [POSIX Time Zone Specifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html)
- [SET TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)