# Postgresql timestamp select not finding values

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column in PostgreSQL lets call it `last_update`. 
I discovered that when I query a field that has not been updated for 6 months it is not found ie.

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE last_update = '2015-03-29 03:36:31.012000';
```

and if I do

```
SELECT last_update FROM example WHERE id = 1234;
```

the result is `2015-03-29 03:36:31.012000` so i know the timestamp should be found.

The

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE last_update = '2015-10-21 10:15:00.468000';
```

query works for example, its just the entries that have not been updated since exactly the 29th of march that cannot be found with select.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how can i fix it? Could it be that the database is corrupt?

Comment: Did you refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277170/postgresql-wrong-converting-from-timestamp-without-time-zone-to-timestamp-with-t ?

Comment: Could be caused the implicit data type conversion. Did you try: `where last_update = timestamp '2015-03-29 03:36:31.012000'`

Comment: And what is your Postgres version ? (before 8.4 ?)

Comment: hi, my postgres version is 9.3.9 the following works `select id from example where last_update = '2015-03-29 02:36:31.012000';
` but the following does not work `select id from example where last_update = timestamp '2015-03-29 03:36:31.012000';
` so it is a timestamp problem i just cannot figure out why

Comment: date +%Z command in all my servers shows CEST and postgresql is an amazon rds instance with timezone UTC